# Using the Jquery Position function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am working on something which will basically create a business card online.

I'm trying to lay out the `div` tags with CSS. Then I want to grab the `x` and `y` co-ordinates of the `div` tags relative to their container so that it can be passed on to PHP GD library so that the image can be made.

I tried using the `.position()` function in jquery but its giving the relative position.

Does anyone have any pointers that may help?

Comment: I think you're thinking you're going to be able to take a screenshot of the image using the PHP GD library? Is this the case? I don't think this is going to do what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [jQuery dimensions plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/dimensions) to find the correct position of an element.

**EDIT:**
As mentioned in the comments, the dimensions plugin was merged into the core. Documentation can be found here: [offset](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/offset) and here [position](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/position).

The linked example could be extended like this: Replace the following code

```
var x = $("#Company_Name").position().left;
var y = $("#Company_Name").position().top;

$("p:last").text( "Full Name: left: " + x + ", top: " + y );
```

with this:

```
var $companyname = $("#Company_Name");
var x = $companyname.position().left;
var y = $companyname.position().top;
var ax = $companyname.offset().left;
var ay = $companyname.offset().top;

$("p:last").text( "Full Name: left: " + x + "/" + ax + ", top: " + y + "/" + ay);
```

notice, I searched the element only once and stuffed it into a variable. That's a good idea if the search can take some time.

**EDIT2:**
I just realized, that this does not work as I expected it. I wrote some function to calculate the relative position:

```
function toString(obj){
        return "{top: " + obj.top + " left: " + obj.left + "}";
    }

    function getRelativePosition(selector){

        var $parentElem = $("#parentElem");
        var $element = $(selector);

        var elementPosition = $element.position();
        var parentPosition = $parentElem.position();

        return {top: elementPosition.top - parentPosition.top, 
            left: elementPosition.left - parentPosition.left};
    }

  $(document).ready(function(){

        var position = $("#Company_Name").position();
        var relativePosition = getRelativePosition("#Company_Name");

        $("p:last").text("position: " + toString(position) + " relativePosition: " + toString(relativePosition));
    });
```

Let me know if this works for you. And someone may tell me what the difference between position and offset in jQuery :-\

**EDIT3:**
To get the position of more then one element, you could call the functions with different ids or give them all the same name or the same class to have something to select them all. Here is a working example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function toString(obj){
    return "{top: " + obj.top + " left: " + obj.left + "}";
}

function getRelativePosition(selector){

    var $parentElem = $("#parentElem");
    var $element = $(selector);

    var elementPosition = $element.position();
    var parentPosition = $parentElem.position();

    return {top: elementPosition.top - parentPosition.top, 
        left: elementPosition.left - parentPosition.left};
}

$(document).ready(function(){

$(".cardfield").each(function(i){

    var position = $(this).position();
    var relativePosition = getRelativePosition(this);

    $("p:last").append("element: " + this.id + " position: " + toString(position) + " relativePosition: " + toString(relativePosition) + "<br>");

});
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<br><br><br><br><br>

<div id="parentElem" style="margin: 0px; top:10px; background-color: #ddd;">
<br><br>
<div class="cardfield" id="Company_Name1">Foo Bar</div>
<br>
<div class="cardfield" id="Company_Name2">Company Name</div>
<div class="cardfield" id="firstname" style="float: right;">Tim</div><br/>
<div class="cardfield" id="lastname" style="float: right;">B&uuml;the</div>
<br><br>
</div>

</p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: I gave all fields the class "cardfield" and used the jQuery to select them. Then I used the [each](http://docs.jquery.com/Each) function to work with the elements. Inside the function I gave to each, "this" refers to the current object.

Comment: that plugin has been part of jquery core since 1.3 (i think)

Comment: I read this also, but they only took the most popular or functions or something, right? Could you provide a pointer?

Comment: Hey yeah this plugin has been mentioned before does anyone know and good documentation on it that can help me use it for a tiny example of code on how to show the position of the div tag relative to container ?

Comment: hey thanks for your reply but atm it's still not getting me the position relative but i'll keep on trying though. i was wondering if you've got any spare time on your hands so that you could possibly get this working for me. 

Willing to pay and i know its not going to be cheap and that's fine !

Comment: hey got the code working not but offer still stands if u would like some work :)

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I have no free time at all. Have you tried my "getRelativePosition" function?

Comment: hey i was wondering how would i edit this so that it will show the position of multiple elements ?

Comment: @Tim Büthe -- Hey ! Thanks ! This saved my lot of time ! :)

Answer (score 0):

For Perfect Position of the element with Absolute

```
var position = window.jQuery(this).position();

var parent_pos = window.jQuery(this).parent().position();

var xpos = position.top - parent_pos.top;
var ypos = position.left - parent_pos.left;
```

if you whole the parent div name or id then you can write as follow

```
var parent_pos = window.jQuery(this).parent('#cardcreate').position();
```

this works perfectly for it.